# Problemas no envio do JSON por POST quando compilado

Tags: java, json, post, jar

Estou com uma aplicação cujo um dos módulos é responsável pelo envio de um JSON para uma API online que faz a sincronização dos dados com um sistema retaguarda. Quando esse módulo é executado ou debugado em uma IDE, ele realiza essa tarefa com sucesso, porém, quando executado na aplicação instalada no Windows (.jar) o mesmo não funciona e retorna um erro 500 da API, da qual já entrei em contato com o desenvolvedor dela e o mesmo não consegue disponibilizar o log pra mim por ser um handler. Cogitei a possibilidade de ser então permissões ou algum bloqueio no firewall já que na IDE funciona e na aplicação não, portanto desativei tudo e continuou com o mesmo problema. É usado a biblioteca javax.net, inclusive em um outro módulo que é feito uma requisição parecida com menos fluxo de dados, ela se comunica com a API corretamente.

Segue o trecho do código em que é feito o envio:

```
URL url = new URL(urlPost);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    UploadRetaguardaModel upload = new UploadRetaguardaModel();
    upload.montarJsonPrincipal();
    JSONObject main = upload.mainObject;
    upload.closeConnection();

try {

    //add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    // Send post request
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
    os.write(main.toString().getBytes());
    os.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    [...]
}
```

Erro que retorna no stacktrace:

> ```
> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: [...]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
> ```

**Atualização:**
  Este trecho de código funcionou corretamente no Linux Mint, no Windows 10 e 7 (nos quais foram testados) permanece esse erro.

Comment: Poste a mensagem com o erro completo.

Comment: Tente ver se o serviço que você está consumindo está com o crossorigin desabilitado.

Comment: certo @VictorHugo, vou checar aqui e já dou um feedback

Comment: @VictorHugo, o crossorigin foi habilitado para qualquer origem de requisição (*) pra testar e o mesmo erro permaneceu.

Comment: @Henrique Veja isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5359/132

Comment: Você consegue por meio de wireshark ou coisa semelhante, capturar os pacotes que trafegam para tentar encontrar diferenças significativas entre o que o programa no JAR manda e o que o programa rodando na IDE manda?

Comment: opa, verdade, não tinha pensado nisso, vou instalar aqui e já dou um retorno.

Comment: O wireshark ajudou a achar algumas diferenças, porém, mesmo deixando os headers idênticos permaneceu dando erro, então eu mudei para a biblioteca do apache e foi com sucesso. Problema resolvido.